# How to login a memeber and view his own detail relationships,contribution

Tags: civimember, civicrm-home, wp

I just use civiCrm and create a member but now I want to below functionality so please guide me how o I can achieve it:- 
1) Login the member from 
2) view his all detail like his contribution, relationship
but problem is that when I creating a contact so it does not generate a username and password please help me for achieving it. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, CiviCRM does not create users, it only creates contact records. You will need to add any users in manually as you normal would through your CMS.

Comment: Welcome to SE.  There are several parts to this - the title is about viewing relationships & contributions but then you talk about generating usernames and passwords.  Can you clarify which bits are working and what you are wanting to do?